# Using while loop to display many users, but if the user already is displayed, don't display again

Tags: php

I have the following query:

```
<ul id="active_con" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <?php
// getting all the conversations which concern the user logged on.
$con = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE message_from='$username' OR message_to='$username'");
while ($get_con = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con)) {
    $msg_from = $get_con['message_from'];
    $msg_to   = $get_con['message_to'];

    echo "<li role='presentation'>
            <a href='http://localhost/messages.php?u=$user'>$msg_to</a>     
        </li>";
}
?>
```

I am trying to display the users who have messaged the user logged in based on `$msg_to` variable. Assume I am logged in as `Fred` and I have sent three messages to `Alice`. The messages are stored in the database in three rows.

Using the query above, I am trying to display active conversations and for each user, make an `li` where I can input their name and profile images later on.

The thing is, the same user is being depicted more than one. Like I mentioned, Fred has an active conversation with Alice - three messages have been sent to Alice, so the `echo` is printing `Alice` three times.

How can I get it so that it only prints a users name once?

Comment: Two words: node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just track what you've already displayed in an array. Something like:

```
$displayed = [];

while ($get_con = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con)) {
    $msg_from = $get_con['message_from'];
    $msg_to   = $get_con['message_to'];

    if(!in_array($msg_to, $displayed)) {
        echo "<li role='presentation'>
            <a href='http://localhost/messages.php?u=$user'>$msg_to</a>     
        </li>";
        $displayed[] = $msg_to;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my code exactly like you have stated, doesn't seem to work. Same user is still being displayed more than once?

Comment: @Freddy my bad, I had the wrong array function. See updated answer.

Comment: @Freddy It is `$msg_to` that you only want to display once, right?

Comment: Both. Alice can send a message to someone for it to be classed as an "active conversation", or receive a message from someone. I need to show users from `$msg_from` and `$msg_to` in the `<li>` element. I hope I have explained that well?